# Tracking Users After Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm very new to google analytics, so my question is rather conceptual. We use GA to track sessions on my company's website. We're most interested in the sessions that convert into trials. We have this as one of our GA goals.

I've implemented an ETL that pulls from the GA Reporting API into our Data Warehouse. However, now that I have the ETL in place, I'm realizing that the way GA has been configured on our site will be of limited value because I have no way of joining my GA data with my internal customer data.

What's the best way to join my GA sessions to a particular customer after they've converted into a trial customer. Is it possible for me to share my company's internal customer_id with google at the point of trial signup and then retrieve that through the API during my ETL runs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're aware of it, but Google Analytics has the ability to add custom dimensions. In your case, you could set the customer_id as a custom dimension to the users session when the trial is signed up for.

If you are using Google Tag Manager then you could make the customer_id available as a datalayer variable and then add this as custom dimension in the GA tag set-up.

Custom dimension set up is described in more detail here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en This contains numerous examples regarding scope and code implementation on the page.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en This describes set-up using a datalayer push and then the eventual set-up for a GA tag.

Custom dimensions have 3 available scopes - hit, session and user. In your case the user scope would be most appropriate as this means that subsequent sessions from this user (assuming they do not use a different device or delete cookies) will continue be labelled with the customer_id irrespective of whether they sign up again or not.

Edit - you could include within the custom dimension, or in an separate dimension sent at the same time, the date of the conversion event.